# Is there a version of Debian-Lenny that is legal for export from the US?

Tags: linux, debian, export

I wanted to bundle my application in a Debian-Lenny Virtual Machine so others could download it and run it without having to configure anything. However, I don't want to have to worry about US legal issues. Many of the packages in a default Debian installation include encryption algorithms.

Are all default versions export-safe?

If not, is there an export-safe version?

If not, is there an easy way to make one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading information at http://www.bis.doc.gov/encryption/pubavailencsourcecodenofify.html, it seems that all I have to do is send an e-mail to the government notifying them of what I'm doing. Since Debian-Lenny is already available world-wide, I don't think that they will have any issues with it.

However, you must consult a lawyer if you really want a definitive answer.